# Unable to execute dex error for android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error, dex

Hi I am developing small android application using eclipse tool. I am including two jar files into my project support version-4 and another is my library jar file. When I ran my application it run successfully but i tried to use it gives me some errors regarding no class def found error. So I do to project properties and there in java build path order and export I checked two jar files. After that i clean build my project and try to run my project. SO while running my project it gives me error. Run time error is as follow:

```
[2013-07-08 12:19:16 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/haarman/listviewanimations/ArrayAdapter;
[2013-07-08 12:19:16 - ListViewAnimationExample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/haarman/listviewanimations/ArrayAdapter;
```

I check around this problem and according solution I delete my bin and gen folder and also tried again run but it gives me same error. How to solve this problem. Is it related to my project set up or its related to eclipse? Need Help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a build path issue. Check that your bin folder is not part of your build path. Typically you get this when you have two of the same jars, but with different versions. Are you using external libraries like ActionBarSherlock? If the android-support-v4 jar you include is a different version than the one ActionBarSherlock uses you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

[Unable to execute error solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778767/unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-f/21137273?noredirect=1#comment32294935_21137273)

Also check Make sure that the value of android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml matches target=android- in project.properties.