# can't compile android project - menu issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

I have a project in eclipse for some android application. by default it was created without menu, bu now I've tried to add some...

I can't compile a project - getting this message

```
[2014-04-04 08:10:27 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-04-04 08:10:27 - mksSQL] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

I've added the following menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: some times it is the problem with your api version, clean the project and try

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building/19803777#19803777)

Comment: check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778767/unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happen at times with eclipse.

Try the following ways

#1 Try `cleaning` your project and `build` again.
or

#2 Right click on your `Project` → go to `Android tools` → and click `android support library.` then clean and build your project.

HIH.

Comment: are you using any jar files your libs folder and Java Build Path?