# Android app is not running on device

Tags: android

```
[2014-04-09 11:50:19 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-04-09 11:50:19 - audiomediaplayer1] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

Comment: refer following links, answer will be there

[link 1][1]
[link 2][2]
[link 3][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741758/bufferoverflowexception-when-building-application
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778767/unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-f

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the value of android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml matches target=android- in project.properties. If these two values are not the same, building with build tools will end in the BufferOverflowException.

Also try this

```
Right click your project → android tools → android support library.
```